# have a problem with syncing object in the texture paint

Tags: texture-painting

I am beginner in blender ,

In the texture paint, the object is not syncing with the other side(I do not know what is the name of that side!)

[image]

[image]
 I am using blender 2.81
thanks for your guide(s) :)

+the problem has been solved :)

Comment: This is weird. Can you provide the .blend via http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ - and then edit and paste the code bit into your answer

Comment: @Manu Järvinen  the problem has been solved :)
thank you :)

Comment: Great great! :)